# With EZ Drummer 2, when do you use a midi pack versus an EZX?

Tags: recording, drums

With EZ Drummer 2, when do you use a midi pack versus an EZX extension? I'm not sure when to use one versus the other.

Comment: is a ezx extension not just a bunch of new sounds with some new midi tracks?

Comment: Is that a question or a statment?

Comment: It's a question. I have some ezx extensions and they allow me to load up new drum kits and come with their own midi-tracks. I am pretty sure it is just a bunch of new sounds with new midi tracks, but not a 100% (maybe i missed something).